# Getting a 302 response to my microcontroller but not to postman?

Tags: google-apps-script, esp32

I'm sending a get request to my apps script from my microcontroller and its returning a 302 although when I request from postman I get a 200? Does anyone have any idea whats going on here? Here's the response headers and response:

```
Response Headers:
    Content-Type : text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
    Cache-Control : no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma : no-cache
    Expires : Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
    Date : Tue, 02 Mar 2021 21:04:31 GMT
    Location : https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=zelsIoIalPSN2brC0Ucwm8KErWsGngFzg3-RfIKKoFhB-TC6uc1StPYE9BZ_6BTOD2biigVTX8niN5E79oBu8ueNSxgDLkcgOJmA1Yb3SEsKFZqtv3DaNYcMrmhZHmUMWojr9NvTBuBLhyHCd5hHa7ei_lA4UjdzA0HOq-9axFFfVZ9KGEnuHPSmwni1hyk6iDJynKJ3CBqbqlbgGEEvpUd579GOljK4AMXDeW9ltFitnlNC15LBrOtvNFeZBCKPCRWEug3jF7jPBmOj32zQcqoYE01sWW00Xz3hUTq3dXcIZ-nkxRkJc5wKdCNugX5Ze5ERSdO3706zPPNASHCYLA&lib=MWEOgn9XagWcbCIn8zJLe3PqOnSALuAMd
    Content-Security-Policy : script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-PBuJkJjKxMQRpM3M1MHVXQ' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /cspreport
    X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff
    X-Frame-Options : SAMEORIGIN
    X-XSS-Protection : 1; mode=block
    Server : GSE
    Alt-Svc : h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
    Accept-Ranges : none
    Vary : Accept-Encoding
    Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Response:
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=zelsIoIalPSN2brC0Ucwm8KErWsGngFzg3-RfIKKoFhB-TC6uc1StPYE9BZ_6BTOD2biigVTX8niN5E79oBu8ueNSxgDLkcgOJmA1Yb3SEsKFZqtv3DaNYcMrmhZHmUMWojr9NvTBuBLhyHCd5hHa7ei_lA4UjdzA0HOq-9axFFfVZ9KGEnuHPSmwni1hyk6iDJynKJ3CBqbqlbgGEEvpUd579GOljK4AMXDeW9ltFitnlNC15LBrOtvNFeZBCKPCRWEug3jF7jPBmOj32zQcqoYE01sWW00Xz3hUTq3dXcIZ-nkxRkJc5wKdCNugX5Ze5ERSdO3706zPPNASHCYLA&amp;lib=MWEOgn9XagWcbCIn8zJLe3PqOnSALuAMd">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

302 is a "temporarily moved" redirect.

Postman is processing it for you automatically. The ESP32 is not a very powerful processor; you need to handle it yourself in this environment.

The new location is in the `Location` field in the response header. You'll need extract the location and then do another request to it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, managed to get it working!

Answer (score 2):

GAS Web Apps redirect, hence the response code 302. Postman allow redirects and resolve to 200.

Here's a quote from the Apps Script reference documentation for the [`TextOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) class explaining the situation:

> Due to security considerations, scripts cannot directly return text content to a browser. Instead, the browser is redirected to googleusercontent.com, which will display it without any further sanitization or manipulation.