# Google Apps Script GET and POST controller dont work on IoT devices (ESP32)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a Google Apps Script with a GET and POST controller to write and read a simple cell in a Google Sheet.

On the other side I am using an WRoom ESP32 to interact with those controllers.
In Postman my controllers work perfectly fine and do their job.

Trying to use the controller on the ESP I only get one response:

Http Code: 303

Http Body:

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo?user_content_key=UkD_LeWNZUS5l-_HuXdBfOqG9ouzo-Xvzu3N2juCn0Kf5VXQ8N8tYpY0pn7u04KLr0E02icZ-282LB1M5mCy0-_hZEWRhWM_m5_BxDlH2jW0nuo2oDemN9CCS2h10ox_1xSncGQajx_ryfhECjZEnHuiBQKnbr6bQxta6it7ifAn9L1gIfqqn-Ygd1w70AksIYwsqpefEpg8P3azY5GTxKmU73tpnIo7EIuG1zp5u6OQOHjkKI141Nz9Jw9Md8uu&amp;lib=MZJD-DHXSUoHbV59AgWkfK34UwSaHbk27">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The Google Apps Script Code:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('LampV2');

function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(sheet.getRange('A1').getValue());
}

function doPost(e){
  var val = e.parameter.value;
  if (e.parameter.value !== undefined){
    var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
    range.setValue(val);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(sheet.getRange('A1').getValue());
};
```

ESP32 Code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

//Google root ca
const char* ca_cert = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIIFWjCCA0KgAwIBAgIQbkepxUtHDA3sM9CJuRz04TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADBH\n" \ 
"MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEiMCAGA1UEChMZR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNlcnZpY2VzIExM\n" \ 
"QzEUMBIGA1UEAxMLR1RTIFJvb3QgUjEwHhcNMTYwNjIyMDAwMDAwWhcNMzYwNjIy\n" \ 
"MDAwMDAwWjBHMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEiMCAGA1UEChMZR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNl\n" \ 
"cnZpY2VzIExMQzEUMBIGA1UEAxMLR1RTIFJvb3QgUjEwggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB\n" \ 
"AQUAA4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQC2EQKLHuOhd5s73L+UPreVp0A8of2C+X0yBoJx9vaM\n" \ 
"f/vo27xqLpeXo4xL+Sv2sfnOhB2x+cWX3u+58qPpvBKJXqeqUqv4IyfLpLGcY9vX\n" \ 
"mX7wCl7raKb0xlpHDU0QM+NOsROjyBhsS+z8CZDfnWQpJSMHobTSPS5g4M/SCYe7\n" \ 
"zUjwTcLCeoiKu7rPWRnWr4+wB7CeMfGCwcDfLqZtbBkOtdh+JhpFAz2weaSUKK0P\n" \ 
"fyblqAj+lug8aJRT7oM6iCsVlgmy4HqMLnXWnOunVmSPlk9orj2XwoSPwLxAwAtc\n" \ 
"vfaHszVsrBhQf4TgTM2S0yDpM7xSma8ytSmzJSq0SPly4cpk9+aCEI3oncKKiPo4\n" \ 
"Zor8Y/kB+Xj9e1x3+naH+uzfsQ55lVe0vSbv1gHR6xYKu44LtcXFilWr06zqkUsp\n" \ 
"zBmkMiVOKvFlRNACzqrOSbTqn3yDsEB750Orp2yjj32JgfpMpf/VjsPOS+C12LOO\n" \ 
"Rc92wO1AK/1TD7Cn1TsNsYqiA94xrcx36m97PtbfkSIS5r762DL8EGMUUXLeXdYW\n" \ 
"k70paDPvOmbsB4om3xPXV2V4J95eSRQAogB/mqghtqmxlbCluQ0WEdrHbEg8QOB+\n" \ 
"DVrNVjzRlwW5y0vtOUucxD/SVRNuJLDWcfr0wbrM7Rv1/oFB2ACYPTrIrnqYNxgF\n" \ 
"lQIDAQABo0IwQDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNV\n" \ 
"HQ4EFgQU5K8rJnEaK0gnhS9SZizv8IkTcT4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEMBQADggIBADiW\n" \ 
"Cu49tJYeX++dnAsznyvgyv3SjgofQXSlfKqE1OXyHuY3UjKcC9FhHb8owbZEKTV1\n" \ 
"d5iyfNm9dKyKaOOpMQkpAWBz40d8U6iQSifvS9efk+eCNs6aaAyC58/UEBZvXw6Z\n" \ 
"XPYfcX3v73svfuo21pdwCxXu11xWajOl40k4DLh9+42FpLFZXvRq4d2h9mREruZR\n" \ 
"gyFmxhE+885H7pwoHyXa/6xmld01D1zvICxi/ZG6qcz8WpyTgYMpl0p8WnK0OdC3\n" \ 
"d8t5/Wk6kjftbjhlRn7pYL15iJdfOBL07q9bgsiG1eGZbYwE8na6SfZu6W0eX6Dv\n" \ 
"J4J2QPim01hcDyxC2kLGe4g0x8HYRZvBPsVhHdljUEn2NIVq4BjFbkerQUIpm/Zg\n" \ 
"DdIx02OYI5NaAIFItO/Nis3Jz5nu2Z6qNuFoS3FJFDYoOj0dzpqPJeaAcWErtXvM\n" \ 
"+SUWgeExX6GjfhaknBZqlxi9dnKlC54dNuYvoS++cJEPqOba+MSSQGwlfnuzCdyy\n" \ 
"F62ARPBopY+Udf90WuioAnwMCeKpSwughQtiue+hMZL77/ZRBIls6Kl0obsXs7X9\n" \ 
"SQ98POyDGCBDTtWTurQ0sR8WNh8M5mQ5Fkzc4P4dyKliPUDqysU0ArSuiYgzNdws\n" \ 
"E3PYJ/HQcu51OyLemGhmW/HGY0dVHLqlCFF1pkgl\n" \ 
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

const char* ssid = "mywifi";
const char* password = "mywifipw";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
  
}

void makeGetRequest(){
  if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status
    HTTPClient http;
 
    http.begin("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyj0XWD_pLtZkoke3j4rBOf2GcxCQV2Y1qyvszP3lFTfvm6qS-ZONnohTJnQ4lEL2vh_g/exec", ca_cert); //Specify the URL
    int httpCode = http.GET();                                        //Make the request
 
    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check for the returning code
        String payload = http.getString();
        Serial.println(httpCode);
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
    http.end(); //Free the resources
    delay(5000);
  }
}

void loop() {
  makeGetRequest();
}
```

Comment: I thought that this thread might be the answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/66447703/7108653